# Maintaining Elpy RPC virtualenv

Tags: emacs, elpy

Is the user supposed to maintain Elpy's RPC virtualenv (i.e. updating packages) or does Elpy handle that automatically?

On several occasions I've had to do `elpy-rpc-reinstall-virtualenv` to solve bizarre issues like completion not working (doing `M-x elpy-company-backend` hanging indefinitely) and others.